# SqlDataAdapter.Fill timeout on one server but not the other

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2016 database on two different machines, a production environment and dev environment, both copies of each other with the production database having a few months worth of extra data (1 or 2% more).

My issue is that I have a stored procedure that when I call it, the `DbDataAdapter.Fill(command)` method times out when the connection string points to the production database server, and runs instantly when connected to the dev database server.

Everything else is the same, the stored procedure and the parameters.

When I run the stored procedure directly against the database using SQL Server Management Studio, it runs in under 1 second on the production machine and on the dev machine.

What else can I investigate? I am lost

Code:

```
SqlCommand cmdDev = new SqlCommand();
cmdDev.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xx.x.53;Initial Catalog=Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password");
cmdDev.CommandText = "spName";
cmdDev.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@OwnedByCompanyID", "100"));
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCompanyID", "0");
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", "0");
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID2", "0");
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchID", "0");
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", "");
cmdDev.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Archived", "0");
cmdDev.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adapterDev = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdDev);
DataTable dtDev = new DataTable();
adapterDev.Fill(dtDev); //runs instananeously, and also instantaneously when executed in SSMS

SqlCommand cmdProd = new SqlCommand();
cmdProd.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xx.x.55;Initial Catalog=Prod;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=userid;Password=password");
cmdProd.CommandText = "spName";
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnedByCompanyID", "100");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClientCompanyID", "0");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", "0");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID2", "0");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BranchID", "0");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", "");
cmdProd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Archived", "0");
cmdProd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
SqlDataAdapter adapterProd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdProd);
DataTable dtProd = new DataTable();
adapterProd.Fill(dtProd); //runs for 30+ seconds then times out, but instantaneously when ran in SSMS
```

Comment: Add the code...

Comment: @Gusman The code is identical except for the ip address. I'm not asking for the solution necessarily, rather anything else I can investigate. The code is large and complex and not easy to minimize for posting.

Comment: Then there will be no one who can help you, we can't see the code, the procedure or nothing...

Comment: @Gusman Did you even read the question? But ok, I will attempt to create a minimal version of the code

Comment: Yes, I read it, you tell us there is a stored procedure which in one environment executes immediately and in other not, but without knowing what the procedure does or how the code calls the procedure then there's no way to know what happens.

Comment: What is the activity like on the two servers? I imagine the size of the data and the activity of each server might be very different

Comment: @Gusman I've attached some code I wrote that re-creates the issue

Comment: @AndrewDiamond no significant activity on the production server, everything else is running smoothly. There is a little bit more data on production vs dev. These particular inputs generate 4,600 records on dev, and 5,100 records on prod

Comment: The code seems ok, I would try to check on the server the query when it's running, maybe is not a problem on the query but on the connection. Your test with management studio was done from the same machine?

Comment: I don't know if this will help. Can you try to open and close your connection manually? Open before the fill, then close after the fill. It might be timing out in unwanted times since it is left open.

Comment: Like possibility pointed out above, Have you tried to check basic matters on remote connection. Login, User, Roles, Permissions to execute stored procedures, Firewall against Server and sqlbrowser, authetification mode, sqlbrowser status Ports setting? If some query could be executed instantly, I think default 30 second or more is not the problem. Did you run SSMS on the same machine where production Server is installed ? and logged in as different credential than in the connectionstring ?

Answer (score 1):

> runs for 30+ seconds then times out, but instantaneously when ran in SSMS

This could mean a number of things, but most likely its Parameter Sniffing

There are a few strategies on how to handle this, Ozar covers them pretty well in [this post](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/)

Comment: I added `OPTION (recompile)` to a query (not a stored) executed by .NET and it worked like a charm